# Populate FastAPI cache during startup for an endpoint

Tags: python, fastapi

I develop a FastAPI app that is deployed in GCP on preemptible nodes. This means the node expires whitin 24 hours and therefore, the app is restarted too. The app runs in several replicas behind a loadbalancer.

The app provides mostly static data that changes once in several days or weeks. Some endpoints perform some calculations with the data and the calculations can take some time. That's why I use `fastapi-cache2`.

The cache works and only the 1st call to the endpoint takes considerable amount of time. All consecutive calls are loaded form the cache. Cool thing is that the whole call is cached and therefore no response is created: it's loaded from the cache.

**So far so good.**

But there is a problem with the 1st call: it just takes too long and users who did not hit the cachce complain. And because of the preemtible nodes, it happens at least one in 24 hours.

**So i had an idea to call the endpoint during the startup to populate the cache.** For FastAPI init, I use the recommended [lifespan](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#lifespan). I think it's not a problem if the app start will take several seconds or even minutes (thanks to replicas).

And here I'm stuck right now. How to call the endpoint?

I had a naive idea to call the endpoint via `httpx`. From the logs, I can see that unicorn is running and (probably) listening:

> Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

But the call 'httpx.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/endpoint")' ends with

> httpx.ConnectError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

**Is there a way how to call app's own endpoint during the startup?**

I have a backup plan to move the cache lower: cachce calls to the repository. Doing so, I will be able to call the repo from the startup and populate the cache this way. Drawback of this solution is that the response needs to be created every time the endpoint is called.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)